# Remove the input textbox's BOLD frame

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Goal:
Remove the input textboxs frame's bold only. It is the same looks without the input textboxs frame's bold, it should be a single and simple frame.

Problem:
The input textboxs frame is very bold when you use css code related to  background-image, background-size, background-position.
If you remove these 3 syntax code, the bold of the input textboxs frame will disappear but no icon size and picture will display.

I still want to keep everything without the input textboxs bold frame, just want a simple and single frame, is it possible?

Thank you!

JSbin:
Wiht bold frame
https://jsbin.com/bizayukoro/edit?html,css,output

```css
input.date_picker {
  text-align: center;
  
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/X-office-calendar.svg");
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  background-position: right center;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 18px;
  width: 78px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2021 by anonymous (http://jsbin.com/wibepejeta/3/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

    
    $(function() {
      var today = new Date(),
        weekAgo = new Date(),
        $from = $("#fromDate"),
        $to = $("#toDate");

      var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd";      
      
      $from.datepicker({     
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        firstDay: 1, 
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        maxDate: today,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
        }
      }).datepicker('setDate', weekAgo);

      $to.datepicker({        
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: dateFormat,      
        minDate: today,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
        }
      }).datepicker('setDate', today);

    });    

    
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  } );    
    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="fromDate" readonly class="date_picker" />
  <label for="to">to</label>
  <input type="text" id="toDate" readonly class="date_picker" />
  
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just use `border:0;` in your css to remove borders, or just set it to `border:1px solid;` for thin border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove border using `border:0;` into your css or you can use thin border using `border: 1px solid;`

```css
input.date_picker {
  text-align: center;
  
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/X-office-calendar.svg");
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  background-position: right center;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 18px;
  width: 78px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2021 by anonymous (http://jsbin.com/wibepejeta/3/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

    
    $(function() {
      var today = new Date(),
        weekAgo = new Date(),
        $from = $("#fromDate"),
        $to = $("#toDate");

      var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd";      
      
      $from.datepicker({     
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        firstDay: 1, 
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        maxDate: today,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
        }
      }).datepicker('setDate', weekAgo);

      $to.datepicker({        
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: dateFormat,      
        minDate: today,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
        }
      }).datepicker('setDate', today);

    });    

    
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  } );    
    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="fromDate" readonly class="date_picker" />
  <label for="to">to</label>
  <input type="text" id="toDate" readonly class="date_picker" />
  
 
 
</body>
</html>
```